# Настройка .htaccess для React (+Router) приложения внутри поддиректории

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .htaccess, apache, react-router

Имеется React-сайт, который расположен в директории `mysite.com/admin`. Соответственно `index.html` находится по адресу `mysite.com/admin/index.html`. Сайт содержит роуты типа `/admin/users` или `/admin/tools/removeUser`.

Как настроить `.htaccess`, чтобы при переходе по `mysite.com/admin/что-угодно`, открывался `mysite.com/admin/index.html`, но сам url оставался тем же, чтобы React их подхватил?

Стоит сказать, что на сайте в корневой директории тоже имеется React-сайт. Вот, что пробовал:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#для admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^admin admin/index.html [L]

#для сайта в корне
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Но при переходе на `mysite.com/admin/tools/removeUser` в консоли получаю вот такую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но почему-то с сайтом в корне все работает нормально. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score -1):

< Link to="/admin/Что-угодно" className="more">Что-угодно

const { name } = useParams(); - Про это прочитай по подробнее

< Route path="/admin/:name" exact component={InnerPage} />

В целом надеюсь разберешься.

Кликаешь на ссылку и она будет искать подходящую "маску" и найдет ее в роутере